# Setting boolean value in docker-compose.yaml using environment variable

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

As docker documentation [suggests](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#args) boolean values in a docker-compose file should be enclosed in single quotes to avoid misinterpretation by the YAML parser.
I have docker-compose file that populates some of the values with environment variables of the shell where it gets invoked

```
myservice:
  environment:
    - firstvar: ${MY_FIRST_VAL}
    - ...
    - booleanvar: ${MY_BOOLEAN_VAL}
```

`MY_BOOLEAN_VAL` can be either `true` or `false` and is exposed via a config file.
I tried `'${MY_BOOLEAN_VAL}'` and `"${MY_BOOLEAN_VAL}"` instead of `${MY_BOOLEAN_VAL}`  hoping for `docker stack deploy` to force a bash-like mechanism for neutralising the YAML parser to no avail.

How can I pass a boolean value using an environment variable to compose file?

Comment: Hey, have you tried setting MY_BOOLEAN_VAL to `'true'` in your config file?

Comment: It is like `export MY_BOOLEAN_VAL='true'` in bash file and the quotes get removed when I invoke it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you've mixed up syntax, try:

```
environment:
  - booleanvar=${MY_BOOLEAN_VAL}
```

or

```
environment:
  booleanvar: ${MY_BOOLEAN_VAL}
```

Comment: Using  `- booleanvar='${MY_BOOLEAN_VAL}'` solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
environment:
  booleanvar: ${MY_BOOLEAN_VAL}
```

`docker-compose` <- `v1` not working...

#### use docker compose v2

```
docker compose -f docker-compose.yaml down
docker compose -f docker-compose.yaml build
docker compose -f docker-compose.yaml up -d
```

https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-images/issues/170