# Docker Compose - set boolean from environment variable

Tags: docker, docker-compose

My Docker Compose expects a boolean ([docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/build/#no_cache)):

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  backend:
    build:
      no_cache: ${NO_CACHE}
```

I trigger the build like this:

```
NO_CACHE=true docker compose up
```

But I get the error

```
services.backend.build.no_cache must be a boolean
```

I've tried replacing `${NO_CACHE}` with `'${NO_CACHE}'` and `"${NO_CACHE}"` after reading [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54073086/3977061) as well as the [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#environment), but I get the same error in both cases.  How can I inject a boolean from environment variables into a Docker Compose field?

```
$ docker -v 
Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701
```

Comment: Not sure it would work, but have you also tried setting the variable in a `.env` file?

Comment: Tried it myself, and no setting the variable in a `.env` file also doesn't work.

Comment: this https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/537/why-is-one-not-allowed-to-use-a-boolean-in-a-docker-compose-yml could help

Comment: indeed there seems to be an issue with passing `build.no_cache` as arg. solutions like `export` var or `.env` file wont work here for some reason (bug ?).

see suggestion for alternative solution using `--build` flag

Answer (score 2):

If the issue is that Docker Compose does not natively support injecting boolean values from environment variables (because environment variables are always treated as strings, [enclosed in quotes](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#environment)), then you might need a wrapper script (to wrap the `docker compose up` call).

For testing, try and write a shell script (`run-docker.sh` + `chmod 755 run-docker.sh`) to read the environment variable and then set the `no_cache` option in the `docker-compose.yml` file based on the value of that variable.
You would then use `docker-compose` to build your services using the now correctly set `no_cache` option.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Read the environment variable
NO_CACHE=${NO_CACHE:-false}

# Determine the value to set in the docker-compose file
if [ "$NO_CACHE" = "true" ]; then
  NO_CACHE_VALUE="true"
else
  NO_CACHE_VALUE="false"
fi

# Update the docker-compose file with the determined value
sed -i.bak -e "s/no_cache: .*/no_cache: $NO_CACHE_VALUE/" docker-compose.yml

# Run docker-compose up
docker compose up

# Restore the original docker-compose file
mv docker-compose.yml.bak docker-compose.yml
```

This script assumes that your `docker-compose.yml` contains a line that matches the regular expression `no_cache: .*`. You will need to adjust the `sed` command if your file is structured differently.

Then call it with:

```bash
NO_CACHE=true ./run-docker.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

alternative solution - getting the same result - passing as external arg to docker-compose command

change your `docker-compose.yaml` and remove `no_cache`:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
```

in order to enforce image build use `--build` flag (`docker compose up --build`)

if you wish to add it as an arg - you can do something like:

```bash
export CUSTOM_FLAGS="--build" # similar to NO_CACHE=true
export CUSTOM_FLAGS="" # similar to NO_CACHE=false

docker compose up $CUSTOM_FLAGS
```

Answer (score 0):

Set environment variable:

```
export NO_CACHE=false
```

Comment: Thanks. I already export it in my docker compose command above.  If I remove `NO_CACHE=true` from the command, I get a warning about a missing env variable.  I also tried explicitly using `export NO_CACHE=true` but I get the same error